# Trying to output JS data from webpage into .html output file

Tags: python, html, json, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have successfully managed to scrape the website listed from JS into a local .html file, but the output falls short.

The issues are:

- it only produces the last query (audioSource) and not the other requests
- it finds only episode 1, and stops there. How do I make it repeat until it finds the end?

Many thanks

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

JSONDATA = requests.request("GET", "https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-json/criminal/v1/episodes?posts=1000000&page=1")
JSONDATA = JSONDATA.json()

for line in JSONDATA['posts']:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(line['episodeNumber'],'lxml')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(line['title'],'lxml')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(line['image']['large'],'lxml')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(line['excerpt']['long'],'lxml')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(line['audioSource'],'lxml')
with open("output1.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(soup))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is :

1. using `w` when writing, it replaces the whole file with updated text.
2. using the same variable name `soup` for all values.
3. You don't need `bs4` module here to parse the json data.

What you can do is :

Install `pandas` module and create a dataframe.
install it using **pip** : `pip install pandas` or **conda** :  `conda install pandas`.

Then you can use the `dataframe` and use it however you like.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import os

JSONDATA = requests.request("GET", "https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-json/criminal/v1/episodes?posts=1000000&page=1")
JSONDATA = JSONDATA.json()

df = pd.DataFrame(JSONDATA)

filename = 'Output.txt'
os.mknod(filename) #create the filename above.

with open(filename, 'a') as fopen:
    for i in range(len(df)):
        fopen.writelines(df.posts[i]['episodeNumber']+'\n')
        fopen.writelines(df.posts[i]['title']+'\n')
        fopen.writelines(df.posts[i]['image']['large']+'\n')
        fopen.writelines(df.posts[i]['excerpt']['long']+'\n')
        fopen.writelines(df.posts[i]['audioSource']+'\n')
        fopen.writelines("\n")
fopen.close()
```

This is the full code what you want.
Additionally you can use `print(df.head())` to see how the dataframe stores the values as a dictionary and do more things.

Output :
[image]

You can see the whole text [here](https://pastebin.com/AA6ezMDg)

Comment: Thanks. Running that gives me this output error:  
  
File "./test4.py", line 19, in <module>  

fopen.writelines(df.posts[i]['excerpt']['long']+'\n')TypeError: writelines() argument must be a sequence of strings  

It produces the file, but only produces the first 3 outputs and there's no excerpt or audioSource link? Also, it only produces the first result - i.e. episode 116, how would I get it to repeat til the very end i.e. episode 1?

Comment: This is self explanatory.  You need to pass string values. So you can do `fopen.writelines(str(df.posts[i]['excerpt']['long']+'\n'))`

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas` library, save data into `CSV` file at the current project directory

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

resp = requests.get("https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-json/criminal/v1/episodes?posts=1000000&page=1").json()
df = pd.DataFrame(resp['posts'], columns=['episodeNumber', 'title', 'image','excerpt','audioSource'])
#it will save data into post csv file and stored in current project directory
df.to_csv("posts.csv")
```